# Rounded corners in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

This feels like it has to be possible, but I cannot figure out if I can do it relatively simply in a `theme()` or have to dig deeper.

I would like to round the corners on the plot areas of my `ggplot2` plots. How would I go about doing that?

Question inspired by: https://twitter.com/Hoog10HK/status/951305194809143296

Comment: Someone has done the &quot;this doesn&#39;t feel right&quot; approach before: https://www.r-bloggers.com/rounded-corners-in-ggplot2-graphics/

Comment: Mmm: a version of `element_rect` that takes a couple of extra options for roundedness and switches in a `grid.roundedRect` (or one wrapped by a `gTree`, maybe) seems like the intuitive way to go

Comment: @rensa I'll need to dig into exactly what element_rect actually returns. If it's possible to put the roundedness in there without breaking everything that uses the return, it definitely feels possible.

Comment: @rensa: `element_rect` is just a data structure. You can't make it draw rounded rectangles.

Comment: There is now a package for rounded corners in ggplot2: https://github.com/botan/ggrounded

I haven't dug in to see how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to theme element subclassing in ggplot2 v3.0.0, I was able to implement a more general approach in a github package with `elementalist::element_rect_round()`. (disclaimer: I wrote that github package)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(elementalist) # devtools::install_github("teunbrand/elementalist")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ cyl) +
  theme(
    legend.background = element_rect_round(radius = unit(0.2, "snpc")),
    legend.key = element_rect_round(radius = unit(0.4, "snpc")),
    panel.background = element_rect_round(radius = unit(1, "cm")),
    strip.background = element_rect_round(radius = unit(8, "pt")),
    plot.background  = element_rect_round(fill = "#C4E7FF")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 20):

You can replace the background grob with a round rectangle:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# make a plot with blue background
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#C4E7FF"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))

# switch out background grob
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
bg <- g$grobs[[1]]
round_bg <- roundrectGrob(x=bg$x, y=bg$y, width=bg$width, height=bg$height,
                          r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                          just=bg$just, name=bg$name, gp=bg$gp, vp=bg$vp)
g$grobs[[1]] <- round_bg

# draw both plots side by side
cowplot::plot_grid(p, g, labels = c("rectangular", "rounded"),
                   scale = 0.85, hjust = 0.5, label_x = 0.5)
```

[image]

The same trick could be applied to the panel background, legend background, etc., if you wanted other aspects of the plot to be rounded.

Comment: I guess we were overengineering the problem a little; I forgot you could just go in and modify the grobs after plotting!