# R Multiple rounded corners rectangles in ggplot2 panel layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap, rounded-corners, grob

I'm trying to create treemaps with rounded corners, like this one [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXD4.png).

I'm using the treemapify package.

I've tried using Claus Wilke solution for changing the background rectangle with a rounded rectangle found here:  [Rounded corners in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199791/rounded-corners-in-ggplot2#)

```
tm <- ggplot2::ggplot(G20, ggplot2::aes(area = gdp_mil_usd, fill = region)) +
  geom_treemap() # save treemap ggplot
gg <- ggplotGrob(tm) # save as grob
rects <- gg$grobs[[6]]$children[[3]] # grobs[[6]] is the panel, and [[3]] are the rect()
```

Then I try to switch the rect grob with a roundrectGrob

```
rounded_rects <- roundrectGrob(x=rects$x, y=rects$y, width=rects$width, height=rects$height,
                r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                just=rects$just, name=rects$name, gp=rects$gp, vp=rects$vp)
```

Gives me the error:

```
Error in validDetails.roundrect(x) : 
  'x', 'y', 'width', and 'height' must have length 1
```

The problem I think is that the roundrectGrob() function "Draw *a single* rectangle with rounded corners.", while here we have a list of rectangles.

How can I swap one single rectGrob with a list of roundrectGrob?

In fact if I pick only the one element, it works fine ( [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I92iW.png) ) but of course plots just the first rectangle:

```
rounded_rects <- roundrectGrob(x=rects$x[[1]], y=rects$y[[1]], width=rects$width[[1]], height=rects$height[[1]],
                r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                just=rects$just, name=rects$name, gp=rects$gp, vp=rects$vp)
gg$grobs[[6]]$children[[3]] <- rounded_rects
cowplot::plot_grid(gg)
```

I tried making a list of roundrects, but it won't let me substitute a list of roundrects to one rect element

```
rounded_rects <- lapply(1:n, function(i) roundrectGrob(x=rects$x[[i]], y=rects$y[[i]], width=rects$width[[i]], height=rects$height[[i]],
                                                       r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                                                       just=rects$just, name=rects$name, gp=rects$gp, vp=rects$vp))
```

Thank you for your help!