# Non-rectangular legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

How could I produce a legend that is not a rectangle with `ggplot`?
For example, how could I get round(ish) corners instead of these sharp corners?

Everybody knows them, but here is one example:

```
ggplot(baseball, aes(year, r)) +
  geom_point(aes(col=g))
```

[image]

Would something similar to this: [Rounded corners in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199791/rounded-corners-in-ggplot2/48220347) maybe work?

Answer (score 2):

The particular strategy mentioned in the linked post is likely going to fail because the colourbar isn't parameterised as a rectangle but rather as a raster. The alternative strategy then is to draw white, inverted quarter circles near the corners.

One way of doing that is to define your own class of colour bar, and add some code that draws these white corners. The code below should work for vertical colour bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(grid)

# Custom constructor, just tags on another class
my_round_colourbar <- function(...) {
  guide <- guide_colourbar()
  class(guide) <- c("my_round_colourbar", class(guide))
  guide
}

# Customised drawing code that adds the corners
guide_gengrob.my_round_colourbar <- function(...) {
  # Use the usual drawing method
  grob <- NextMethod()
  # Find the bar from the normal legend
  is_bar <- grep("bar", grob$layout$name)[[1]]
  bar <- grob$grobs[[is_bar]]
  # Measure the bar
  width  <- convertUnit(bar$width, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
  height <- convertUnit(bar$height, "cm", valueOnly = TRUE)
  minor <- min(width, height)
  # Draw 'caps': 2 inverted corner pieces
  t <- seq(0, pi, length.out = 180)
  cap <- data.frame(
    x = c((cos(t) / 2), -0.5, 0.5) * minor,
    y = c((-sin(t) / 2) + 0.5, 0, 0) * minor
  )
  # Draw a polygon for each cap
  bottom <- polygonGrob(x = unit(cap$x, "cm") + bar$x, 
                        y = unit(cap$y, "cm") + bar$y - 
                          unit(height * 0.5, "cm"), 
                        gp = gpar(fill = "white",col = NA),
                        default.units = "cm")
  top <- polygonGrob(x = unit(cap$x, "cm") + bar$x, 
                     y = unit(-cap$y, "cm") + bar$y + unit(height * 0.5, "cm"),
                     gp = gpar(fill = "white", col = NA),
                     default.units = "cm")
  # Add polygon to bar
  bar <- grobTree(bar, top, bottom)
  grob$grobs[[is_bar]] <- bar
  return(grob)
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = drat)) +
  guides(colour = my_round_colourbar())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: ok wow, thank you very very much!! I already expected that there is no simple answer. I really would like to dive deeper into the `grid`-package, because from your code I understand like 10 % haha. Do you know of any more or less easily accessable ggplot-internals literature?

Comment: In the [ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/internals.html) they talk about the internals a bit, though not alot about grid. In [this part](https://ggplot2-book.org/spring1.html#spring4) they explain a bit about grid.

Comment: If you want to explore a bit what the code is doing (and you're using RStudio), you can put in a `browser()` somewhere in the beginning of `guide_gengrob.my_round_colourbar` so you can following along.