# Adding dotted line to guide_colourbar() in a ggplot2 plot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R ggplot2, I would like to add a dotted line to a legend colourbar. Is this possible to do with ggplot2 or will I just have to do it in Illustrator etc - I plan to make a fair few of these and would like to avoid manually setting this.

Example:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this reliably without having to manually change each plot, you could create a new `guide`. The basic idea is described in Teunbrand's answer to a related question about modifying the colour bar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256863/non-rectangular-legend-in-ggplot)

```r
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

guide_linedcolourbar <- function(..., threshold = 1.5) {
  guide <- guide_colourbar(..., threshold = threshold)
  class(guide) <- c("linedcolourbar", class(guide))
  guide
}

guide_gengrob.linedcolourbar <- function(guide, theme) {
  bar_vals <- guide$bar$value
  y <- findInterval(guide$threshold, bar_vals)/length(bar_vals)
  grob <- NextMethod()
  is_bar <- grep("bar", grob$layout$name)[[1]]
  bar <- grob$grobs[[is_bar]]
  line <- linesGrob(y = c(y, y), gp = gpar(col = 'white', lty = 2, lwd = 1))
  grob$grobs[[is_bar]] <- grobTree(bar, line)
  grob
}

data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50), LOD = runif(50, 0.7, 1.8)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = LOD)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis_c(guide = guide_linedcolourbar(threshold = 1.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. From your example, how would I specify the y position/threshold of the dotted line based on some value

Comment: @user22423300 see my update - you can use the `threshold` argument to set the height of the line.